# Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, gitlab-ci, daemon

When I run the CI pipeline, the build fails and get the following log:

```
Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
Build request sent: Build{id=b91f4b26-bf6d-47cf-9b46-91597dd55810, currentDir=/builds/instructorsmatch/immobile/android}
Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
Daemon pid: 600
  log file: /root/.gradle/daemon/6.7.1/daemon-600.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-600.out.log -----
2021-10-10T09:28:11.989+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler] Starting executing command: Build{id=b91f4b26-bf6d-47cf-9b46-91597dd55810, currentDir=/builds/instructorsmatch/immobile/android} with connection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:43227 to /127.0.0.1:58922.
2021-10-10T09:28:11.991+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Command execution: started DaemonCommandExecution[command = Build{id=b91f4b26-bf6d-47cf-9b46-91597dd55810, currentDir=/builds/instructorsmatch/immobile/android}, connection = DefaultDaemonConnection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:43227 to /127.0.0.1:58922] after 0.0 minutes of idle
2021-10-10T09:28:11.992+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Marking the daemon as busy, address: [f132aabb-7423-48d1-8ba5-a5febd0e8b86 port:43227, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2021-10-10T09:28:11.992+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Marking busy by address: [f132aabb-7423-48d1-8ba5-a5febd0e8b86 port:43227, addresses:[localhost/127.0.0.1]]
2021-10-10T09:28:12.001+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-10-10T09:28:12.001+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-10-10T09:28:12.003+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-10-10T09:28:12.003+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] resetting idle timer
2021-10-10T09:28:12.003+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
2021-10-10T09:28:12.006+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy] Daemon is about to start building Build{id=b91f4b26-bf6d-47cf-9b46-91597dd55810, currentDir=/builds/instructorsmatch/immobile/android}. Dispatching build started information...
2021-10-10T09:28:12.006+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 19: dispatching org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@5edfe575
2021-10-10T09:28:12.008+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment] Configuring env variables: [PATH, CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE, CI_SERVER_VERSION_MAJOR, CI_PROJECT_URL, CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG, GITLAB_FEATURES, CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG, ANDROID_HOME, FF_USE_NEW_BASH_EVAL_STRATEGY, CI_PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH, CI_SERVER_VERSION_MINOR, PWD, FF_USE_LEGACY_KUBERNETES_EXECUTION_STRATEGY, CI_SERVER, LANGUAGE, CI_PROJECT_VISIBILITY, CI_PROJECT_TITLE, CI_BUILD_NAME, FF_USE_WINDOWS_LEGACY_PROCESS_STRATEGY, CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE, CI_RUNNER_ID, ANDROID_PLATFORM_VERSION, CI_REGISTRY_USER, CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME, CI_NODE_TOTAL, LC_ALL, CI_SERVER_URL, CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP, SHLVL, CI_BUILD_REF_NAME, CI_REGISTRY, CI_JOB_STATUS, CI_PROJECT_REPOSITORY_LANGUAGES, CI_PAGES_URL, CI_JOB_STAGE, ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS_VERSION, CI_PAGES_DOMAIN, CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX, CI_BUILD_STAGE, CI_RUNNER_REVISION, CI_CONCURRENT_ID, CI_PIPELINE_ID, CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE, CI_JOB_JWT, CI_JOB_IMAGE, CI_BUILD_TOKEN, FF_CMD_DISABLE_DELAYED_ERROR_LEVEL_EXPANSION, CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH, CI_PROJECT_NAME, CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG, CI, FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD, FF_SKIP_NOOP_BUILD_STAGES, CI_JOB_TOKEN, FLUTTER_ALREADY_LOCKED, CI_PROJECT_DIR, CI_RUNNER_VERSION, CI_COMMIT_SHA, FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE, FF_USE_DYNAMIC_TRACE_FORCE_SEND_INTERVAL, CI_SERVER_REVISION, CI_JOB_STARTED_AT, CI_CONCURRENT_PROJECT_ID, CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_USER, CI_PIPELINE_URL, CI_SERVER_PORT, CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA, CI_SERVER_NAME, CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA, CI_JOB_URL, FF_USE_POWERSHELL_PATH_RESOLVER, GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW, CI_BUILDS_DIR, GITLAB_USER_NAME, CI_RUNNER_TAGS, CI_SERVER_VERSION_PATCH, OLDPWD, CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL, ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION, CI_COMMIT_BRANCH, FF_ENABLE_BASH_EXIT_CODE_CHECK, GITLAB_CI, CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE, CI_JOB_ID, GITLAB_USER_ID, CI_PIPELINE_IID, CI_SERVER_VERSION, FF_SCRIPT_SECTIONS, FLUTTER_VERSION, CI_COMMIT_TITLE, CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_SERVER, CI_API_V4_URL, CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE, GITLAB_USER_EMAIL, CI_BUILD_REF, CI_PROJECT_ID, FLUTTER_ROOT, FLUTTER_HOME, CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION, LANG, CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD, CI_PROJECT_PATH, CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED, CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH, CI_DISPOSABLE_ENVIRONMENT, CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR, CI_RUNNER_SHORT_TOKEN, FF_SKIP_DOCKER_MACHINE_PROVISION_ON_CREATION_FAILURE, CI_CONFIG_PATH, CI_BUILD_BEFORE_SHA, CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION, CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_PASSWORD, CI_SERVER_HOST, CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT, FF_DISABLE_UMASK_FOR_DOCKER_EXECUTOR, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, FF_USE_FASTZIP, GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW, FF_USE_DIRECT_DOWNLOAD, CI_BUILD_ID, HOSTNAME, CI_JOB_NAME, GITLAB_USER_LOGIN, CI_REPOSITORY_URL, HOME]
2021-10-10T09:28:12.024+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] About to start relaying all logs to the client via the connection.
2021-10-10T09:28:12.024+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 600). The daemon log file: /root/.gradle/daemon/6.7.1/daemon-600.out.log
2021-10-10T09:28:12.032+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon] Requesting daemon stop after processing Build{id=b91f4b26-bf6d-47cf-9b46-91597dd55810, currentDir=/builds/instructorsmatch/immobile/android}
2021-10-10T09:28:12.032+0000 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
2021-10-10T09:28:12.032+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Stop as soon as idle requested. The daemon is busy: true
2021-10-10T09:28:12.040+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
2021-10-10T09:28:12.040+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon stop has been requested. Sleeping until state changes.
2021-10-10T09:28:12.043+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=9fab3277-279a-4193-a9dc-d89a6d3cb028,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=600,idleTimeout=120000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx4096M,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
----- End of the daemon log -----
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? I tried adding

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
org.gradle.daemon=false
file.encoding=utf-8
```

but none of these worked.

Comment: Can you post the code for your GitLab job? You may be able to run using the `--no-daemon` flag if you're only running one gradle task per gitlab job, as having a persistent daemon process won't help with anything since it will restart with every job anyway.

Comment: build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - flutter build apk
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.apk
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
  - develop

Comment: What is the image you're using in your CI/CD, and are you using a custom runner? I don't see a `tag` command in your job, so I'd guess not, but this is most commonly seen when you have leftover .gradle files somewhere from a previous job. PS - when you include new info, you should edit your question and add it so you can use markdown to display it in code format :)

Answer (score 1):

Enter home/your_username/.gradle, delete daemon. Re enter your project then run.